# migrating application from tomcat 5.5 to tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat7

I am trying to migrate application an application to tomcat 7 from tomcat 5.5.
my questions:

1. Should the servlet configuration should be changed to 3.0 ?
2. If so, I have updated `<web-app>` element in web.xml to 3.0 and
   added jstl-1.2.jar,jstl-api-1.2-rev- 1.jar and jstl-impl-1.2.jar to
   my build path, servlet-api(took from tomcat/lib folder) and in
   WEB-INF/lib folder.
3. Updated c.tld to support servlet 3.0.

After doing all this, I am getting error as

```
forwardDefault(processor.java:221)]-Could not create RequestDispatcher
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: (line: 38, column: 2)
```

According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Can you please advise on this, I have read many blogs and implemented all the solutions but still not sure where I am wrong.

Comment: TLD is handled differently with that version of Tomcat.  You should not have any of those references in your web.xml anymore.

Comment: No, I don't have any reference to tld in my web.xml